# How to get data from failed forkJoin request?

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

Using `Angular` `Rxjs` and `ngrx`

I have an action that dispatch 4 API and I am doing the following =>

```
  @Effect()
  getAllModels$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.GetAllModelsRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.GetAllModelsRequest),
    switchMap((action) =>
      forkJoin([
        this.dataService.GetAllModelFromServer(),
        this.dataService.GetAllModelFromHost(),
        this.dataService.GetAllModelFromCache(),
        this.dataService.GetAllModelFromPreference(),
      ]).pipe(
        map(
          ([server, host, cache, preference]) =>
            new featureActions.GetAllModelsSuccess({
              //...
            })
        ),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          return of(new featureActions.GetAllModelsFailed({ error: error.message }));
        })
      )
    )
  );
```

The problem is, when one of those API fail, everything fail and I am in fail action. all the data that got retrieved (before the one endpoint that failed) is lost.

Is there a way to get the data retrieved in the `catchError` or the only solution is to chain the api one after the other ?

Comment: You can't.  Unless you want to write your own custom 'forkJoin' implementation. i.e. you can tweak this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/forkJoin.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with this solution found here : https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-error-handling-with-forkjoin-3d4027df70fc

```
  @Effect()
  getAllModels$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.GetAllModelsRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.GetAllModelsRequest),
    switchMap((action) =>
      forkJoin([
        this.dataService.GetAllModelFromServer().pipe(catchError(() => of({ data: [] }))),
        this.dataService.GetAllModelFromHost().pipe(catchError(() => of({ data: [] }))),
        this.dataService.GetAllModelFromCache().pipe(catchError(() => of({ data: [] }))),
        this.dataService.GetAllModelFromPreference().pipe(catchError(() => of({ data: [] }))),
      ]).pipe(
        map(
          ([server, host, cache, preference]) =>
            new featureActions.GetAllModelsSuccess({
              //...
            })
        ),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          return of(new featureActions.GetAllModelsFailed({ error: error.message }));
        })
      )
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own implementation of `forkJoin`. Here is a simple example sourced from the original (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/forkJoin.ts):

```
export function forkJoin2(...args: any[]): Observable<any> {
  const resultSelector = popResultSelector(args);

  const { args: sources, keys } = argsArgArrayOrObject(args);

  if (resultSelector) {
    // deprecated path.
    return forkJoinInternal(sources, keys).pipe(map((values: any[]) => resultSelector!(...values)));
  }

  return forkJoinInternal(sources, keys);
}

function forkJoinInternal(sources: ObservableInput<any>[], keys: string[] | null): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable((subscriber) => {
    const len = sources.length;
    if (len === 0) {
      subscriber.complete();
      return;
    }
    const values = new Array(len);
    let completed = 0;
    let emitted = 0;
    for (let sourceIndex = 0; sourceIndex < len; sourceIndex++) {
      const source = innerFrom(sources[sourceIndex]);
      let hasValue = false;
      subscriber.add(
        source.subscribe({
          next: (value) => {
            if (!hasValue) {
              hasValue = true;
              emitted++;
            }
            values[sourceIndex] = value;
          },
          error: (err) => { return subscriber.error({ error: err, values }) },
          complete: () => {
            completed++;
            if (completed === len || !hasValue) {
              if (emitted === len) {
                subscriber.next(keys ? keys.reduce((result, key, i) => (((result as any)[key] = values[i]), result), {}) : values);
              }
              subscriber.complete();
            }
          },
        })
      );
    }
  });
}
```

Notice, when an error occurs, you are returning the error along with the values:

`error: (err) => { return subscriber.error({ error: err, values }) }`